# IntelliJ IDEA good for ColdFusion?

Tags: intellij-idea, coldfusion

I installed IntelliJ IDEA IDE, because it has ColdFusion support, however, I don't see the CF Servers and RDS Dataview, like in ColdFusion Builder IDE.
Is IntelliJ IDEA good after all? Do I have to install additional plugins for coding in ColdFusion?

Comment: You won't get any ColdFusion support in the Community edition, you need Ultimate Edition for that. Also, why do you need to 'see' the CF servers? There is no RDS support, but you can use the database tab to view local and remote databases.

Comment: You can try VS Code with CFML plugin or Sublime Text w/ CFML plugin, but if you want all the bells and whistles, CF Builder is your only option. Especially if you want a step debugger.

Comment: Question - Other than syntax highlighting, how does IntelliJ "enhance" CFML development?  I have IntelliJ 2022 Ultimate, and without Step Debugging or RDS, I fail to see any "support" AT ALL.  Is there some awesome integrated ColdFusion functionality that I am completely MISSING?  I genuinely hope there is because using a beast like IntelliJ JUST for syntax highlighting seems like massive OVERKILL, when WebStorm (which doesn't even support CFML) would be significantly cleaner and faster.